# Unable to reference library in my code-behind

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I'm attempting to use the following ExcelReader library:

http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

The code example shows:

```
//1. Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
```

My application is (unfortunately) in VB.NET. I've wrote the following:

```
Dim excelReader as IExcelDataReader
```

However I just get "IExcelDataReader is undefined".

I've tried importing Excel.dll by doing:

```
Imports Excel
```

But again I just get an error.

Why is this? How can I reference this library?

Comment: Might sound trivial, but did you add project reference to the `Excel.dll` file?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I added a reference to `Excel.dll` and `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll` in my `bin` folder yes

Answer (score 0):

By any chance, is your project defined as .NET 4.0 client profile? If so change it to full .NET 4.0.

Comment: I don't get an error when importing (although intellisense hasn't picked it up). But I do when entering my first line of code, `Type 'IExcelDataReader' is not defined.`

Comment: Thanks for the update. My application is running in .NET 3.5. Sorry I should've specified that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim excelReader As IExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream)
```

Comment: The issue is that the application isn't recognising `IExcelDataReader`

Comment: May be it's the framework it's created for .Net Framework 2 Change the framework reference to 2.0 for this project and try.